# Listview within a TabBar

Tags: flutter

Currently I am using this [tutorial](https://flutter.io/catalog/samples/tabbed-app-bar/) to learn how to build a Tabbed Appbar in Flutter. What I would like to do is to have different pages with a listview as shown [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/website/master/_includes/code/layout/listview/main.dart) in each of the tabs. How can this be done or is there a tutorial I can be pointed to?

Comment: What is the problem, did you setup the TabBar correctly and do not know how to show ListView under each tab ?

Comment: Correct everything with the tab works but the example only shows it with a card. I want to know how to show a listview instead @aziza

Comment: Just replace the card by a listview ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this, no?

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TabbedAppBarSample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: const Text('Tabbed AppBar'),
            bottom: new TabBar(isScrollable: true, tabs: [
              new Tab(text: 'Tab 1', icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              new Tab(text: 'Tab 2', icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_walk)),
              new Tab(text: 'Tab 3', icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ]),
          ),
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: [
              new ListView(
                children: list,
              ),
              new ListView(
                children: list,
              ),
              new ListView(
                children: list,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Widget> list = <Widget>[
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('CineArts at the Empire',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('85 W Portal Ave'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('The Castro Theater',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('429 Castro St'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('Alamo Drafthouse Cinema',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('2550 Mission St'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('Roxie Theater',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('3117 16th St'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('United Artists Stonestown Twin',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('501 Buckingham Way'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('AMC Metreon 16',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('135 4th St #3000'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.theaters,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new Divider(),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('K\'s Kitchen',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('757 Monterey Blvd'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.restaurant,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('Emmy\'s Restaurant',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('1923 Ocean Ave'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.restaurant,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('Chaiya Thai Restaurant',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('272 Claremont Blvd'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.restaurant,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
  new ListTile(
    title: new Text('La Ciccia',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20.0)),
    subtitle: new Text('291 30th St'),
    leading: new Icon(
      Icons.restaurant,
      color: Colors.blue[500],
    ),
  ),
];

void main() {
  runApp(new TabbedAppBarSample());
}
```

Comment: this works as expected thanks....trying to see how to make each item in the list clickable to go to a new page

Comment: @KernElliott did you figure it out?  Just got around to checking again as I have been out of the office.

Comment: hey I didnt figure out how to make each list item clickable but i did get to render the list

Comment: add an onTap to each ListTile.